# How could Harrison beam to Qo'noS?

Tags: star-trek, technology, star-trek-into-darkness

In Star Trek into Darkness Kahn uses Scotty's formula for transwarp beaming (provided by Spock in the 2009 film) to transport from Earth to Qo'noS. However according to Memory Alpha Qo'noS is [90 light years away](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Qo'noS).

However even in the the TNG/Voy/DS9 era transporters are generally only used to beam between ships or down to planets. Shuttles are generally used for longer trips (such as going from DS9 to Bajor which is very close!).

How could Harrison use technology Scotty would develop to beam 90 light years when the same technology isn't available after Scotty's death in the prime universe?

Comment: khan used his supreme intellect, and focused it on specific things, and was apparently able to do a few hundred years of R&D in like 5 years >.>

Comment: The problem the writers created with the whole Trans-Warp beaming creation, is it negates the need for a ship.

Comment: hopefully with the destruction of the vengeance, and of the research facility, all of the "advancedments" khan made to the starfleet tech was lost. so that the 3rd movie they arnt just trolling along space without a care in the world since they have ships fit with tech 100+ years more advanced lol. though spock was from about 40ish years past TNG im pretty sure, so the transwarp equation could be from then based on something scotty was working on when he was still alive.

Comment: It's a completely different universe. Obviously the technology was available in the New Star Trek universe, whereas it wasn't yet in the prime universe.

Comment: @Monty129: This seems appropriate: http://youtu.be/4N15J4ibej8

Comment: @Himarm, why do they need ships? They can beam from planet to planet. Scotty's invention has essentially made Starfleet obselete. (It would be cool if the next movie explores this, but I bet it won't.)

Comment: The Federation essentially have Iconian technology now, and that's kinda bonkers.

Comment: Who says he beamed directly there?

Comment: Nothing about the plot in that whole movie makes sense from a technical standpoint.

Comment: @BBlake other then the teleporting across space, the rest of the tech is realistic in the star trek verse, attacking at warp, faster warp, better shields, bigger weapons are all reasonable things for khan to have helped create. Maybe the device khan used also "broke" or was damaged so they wouldnt be able to use it or recreate it, though they did teleport mulitpul lightyears in the first movie too >.>

Comment: I was thinking more things like distance (traveling from Earth to Qo'nos in mere hours, the Neutral Zone apparently being close enough to visibly see Qo'nos, a battle taking place right at Earth yet no one notices, etc) & physics (the crippled Enterprise somehow drifts from behind the moon to being caught in Earth's gravity and plummeting to the ground in mere moments, yet then falling for like 15 or 20 minutes from being caught in Earth's gravity to the point where Kirk restores power and the Enterprise is saved).  Stupid interpretations of real science as opposed to sci-fi science.

Comment: Harrison didn't beam to Qo'noS. The script very clearly indicates that he beamed to ***Kronos***.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> However even in the the TNG/Voy/DS9 era transporters are generally only used to beam between ships or down to planets.

The issue is that we didn't see Scotty invent this during TNG/VOY/DS9.  Future-Spock came back from later in the 24th Century than any of the previous shows/movies depicted.  Future-Spock hails from [2387](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/2387), whereas *Voyager* ended in [2378](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Voyager), and *Nemesis* occurred in [2379](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/2379).

Scotty was rescued on a Dyson Sphere by the Enterprise-D in [2369](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Scotty), and sometime in the decades between that and 2387, he invented transwarp beaming.  We just never saw this.  It either occurred off-camera while one of the other *Star Trek* series/films was happening, or it occurred in the ~decade afterwards before Spock was sent back in time to the alternate timeline.

> How could Harrison use technology Scotty would develop to beam 90 light years when the same technology isn't available after Scotty's death in the prime universe?

Scotty's not dead.  He invented it off-screen, or after *Nemesis*, which is the latest film in the prime timeline (excepting the flashbacks in *Star Trek (2009)*).  Future Spock brought this technology back in time, and gave it to young Scotty, who in turn gave it to Starfleet.  Starfleet/Section 31 then built a transwarp transporter, which Harrison stole and used.

Comment: Good point, I'd forgotten about the Dyson Sphere!

Comment: Pretty much exactly the answer I was going to give, Keen. Good job!

Comment: Maybe in the future they were somehow able to reverse engineer and duplicate the tech that voyager picked got in the [Prime Factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Factors_\(Star_Trek:_Voyager\)) episode.  Which had a 40,000 light year transport range. Scotty certainly seems like a good person to put in a R&D section to try and figure out alien tech.

Comment: I.e. Scotty just completely undermined the Starship and linear interstellar travel.

Comment: Kinda makes you wonder why Admiral Picard still uses a shuttle to get to the new Stargazer in Picard 2x01...